# How to Disable WebRTC in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, vpn, google-chrome-extensions, webrtc

I understand there are security vulnerabilities exposed when WebRTC is enabled, so I would like to disable it in Chrome. How does one do that?

I thought I'd be able to do it under chrome://flags, which in v48 (64-bit) has the following entries...

- Enable support for WebRTC Stun origin header (disabled)
- Disable Delay Agnostic AEC in WebRTC (disabled)
- Enable negotiation with DTLS 1.2 for WebRTC (disabled)
- Disable support for WebRTC hardware video decoding.(unavailable experiment)
- Disable support for WebRTC hardware video encoding. (unavailable experiment)

I've also tried the following chrome extensions without success

- [WebRTC Leak Prevent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-leak-prevent/eiadekoaikejlgdbkbdfeijglgfdalml?hl=en-US)
- [Anonymous VPN - WebRTC leak prevent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anonymous-vpn-webrtc-leak/gkicmebfnjalhhmhljadbocnjgblkbil?hl=en-US)
- [Whats My IP | Whour.net](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whats-my-ip-whournet/lohmchjkjjlpghmhjemcjdgbaghpgacm?hl=en-US)
- [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en-US)
  (Blocks ads & pop-ups nicely though)

There's one more [WebRTC Leak Prevent Toggle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-leak-prevent-toggl/kignegkkmknfpincglcjggfbgghpamim?hl=en-US) I didn't bother trying because it's made by the same company as the first, which didn't work.

> Note: I'd like to add a new tag [WebRTC] but don't have enough points to do it. If someone else would please add that, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Simply put; you can't; not without an add on [support article](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chrome/gJ8HF-yoG-Y)

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I went through that article as well. I've tried all the solutions they suggested (and updated my description), but nothing works. Do you know of an add on that actually works?

Comment: tag:webrtc created

Comment: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/8204/how-to-stop-webrtc-local-ip-address-leaks-on-google-chrome-and-mozilla-firefox-while-using-private-i

Answer (score 1):

The only major security implication of WebRTC is that it can leak your IP address (both the private/internal an public/external).

It is not possible to disable WebRTC in the desktop version of Chrome, however you can use the [WebRTC Block](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-block/nphkkbaidamjmhfanlpblblcadhfbkdm) extension. (On Android there is a Disable WebRTC flag)